# Access Samba share from Windows 10 in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, virtualbox, samba

I read a lot of user questions and blogs about this concern, but nothing fixed my issue.

I have a Linux CENTOS host with Windows 10 guest installed in VirtualBox. On Linux, there's a user named "myuser" which shares a directory (777) and is registred to Samba user database. This user has no password restriction. The `smb.conf` looks like this:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKSPACE_SHARE
security = user
map to guest = bad user

[public]
path = /home/myuser/public
public = yes
writeable = yes
comment = smb share
printable = no
guest ok = yes
```

Windows has a local user with the same name ("myuser", no password set), file and printer sharing enabled, Microsoft Client enabled, workgroup set which matches the Samba workgroup and uses a private network.

In explorer I can see the Linux host which, indeed, contains the shared folder ("public"). But when a try to access this shared folder, an error alert appears: You do not have permissions to access...

On the internet I read things like "Windows 10 uses SMBv3 but Samba doesn't yet support it" and how to turn SMBv3 off - but it didn't help.

Even modification of Local Security Policies on Windows didn't do the trick: https://superuser.com/a/916835/408191

How can I fix this weird issue?

Comment: try configuring it to use a password, I've had issues before and explicitly setting a password helped

Comment: I just tried your hint (determined password for unix user, for user in Samba user database and for Windows user). It still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: I've created a further VM with Windows 7. Same issue. I'm assuming that there's something wrong with the Samba settings or the share directory's properties?

Comment: I found out that sharing works fine depending on the share directory's location. For instance, on ``/samba/exampleshare`` it works fine. But I want this folder to be located in a user home directory, e.g.: ``/home/myuser/exampleshare``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Linux distributions have a so called SELinux implementation in its kernel. It stands for ["Security-Enhanced Linux"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) and, beside other things, restricts Samba shares. If you want to create a share folder then it's not not enough to specify convenient access permissions and a definition in `samba.conf`. You also need to set the correct "Security Context" of the share folder.

Following permission mask and security context should do the trick:

```
chmod -R 770 yoursharefolder
chcon -R -t samba_share_t yoursharefolder
```

All conditions that are already known from different wikis must also be adhered:

- Unix user as owner of the share must be added to Samba user database: `smbpasswd -a youruser`
- Your windows machine must have a user with the same name and same password as set in Samba database
- Your `samba.conf` may look like this:

`samba.conf` (all upper-case parts must be customized for your concerning specific environment):

```
[global]
workgroup = SAME_WORKGROUP_AS_CONFIGURED_IN_WINDOWS
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = HOST_NAME_OF_YOUR_LINUX_MACHINE_ON_NETWORK
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no

[yourshare]
path = /PATH/TO/YOURSHARE
valid users = YOUR_WINDOWS_USER_NAME
browsable = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
directory mask = 0770
create mask = 0770
```

**Edit:** Note that changes via `chcon` aren't permanent. In order to do permanent security context changes use following command:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t /full/path/to/your/share/folder
```

...and to make it effective:

```
restorecon -v /full/path/to/your/share/folder
```